# Property of a protocol doesn't accept a protocol inheritance

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

#### I have two basic Protocols

```
protocol SubtractsDelegate: class {
    func func1()
}
```

```
protocol AddsDelegate: class {
    func func2()
}
```

#### My third Protocol conforms to both

```
protocol Operates: SubtractsDelegate, AddsDelegate { }
```

#### Then I have another Protocol that requires a property of type `SubtractsDelegate`

```
protocol DoesStuff {
    var delegate: SubtractsDelegate? {get set}
}
```

I have a class that has a property named `delegate` that is of Type `Operates`

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, DoesStuff {
    weak var delegate: Operates?
}
```

## Problem

This `delegate` property on `MyViewController` should conform to both `SubtractsDelegate` and `AddsDelegate` because it conforms to `Operates`

However, the compiler complains and says

> MyViewController does not conform to protocol DoesStuff

## Question

Why is that??? If `Operates` conforms to `SubtractsDelegate`, why doesn't `DoesStuff` protocol accept it as the type of `delegate`?

Comment: I'm not sure, neither seem to directly apply

Comment: agreed. apologies.

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/protocols-question-how-can-i-achieve-covariance-on-a-requirements-implementation/49210/6

Answer (score 0):

Hope it would help

```
protocol SubtractsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func func1()
}

protocol AddsDelegate: AnyObject {
    func func2()
}

protocol Operates: SubtractsDelegate & AddsDelegate { }

protocol DoesStuff {
    associatedtype Proxy: SubtractsDelegate
    var proxy: Proxy? { get set }
}

class MyViewController<T: Operates>: UIViewController, DoesStuff {
    var proxy: T?

    func executeMethods() {
        proxy?.func1()
        proxy?.func2()
    }
}

class ClassOperates: Operates {
    func func1() {
        print("func1")
    }

    func func2() {
       print("func2")
    }
}
```

After in your coordinator or wherever

```
func makeStuff() {
    let ref: MyViewController<ClassOperates> = .init()
    ref.proxy = .init()
    ref.executeMethods()
}
```